# There are a IOException "Error writing to server " when Call Googlesheet batch insert API error

Tags: google-sheets-api

I use google sheet API build a agent. This agent can save input data form anywhere to googlesheet . when the input data is a lot an  error " Error writing to  server "will occurs. There are 454 row and 144 columns  in the input data. error detail info please see the screen shoot.[enter image [enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDT0S.png)description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAAod.png)

Anybody can give me some help on this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried reading this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896568/getting-java-io-ioexception-error-writing-to-server-at-getinputstream / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921426/error-writing-to-server

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this solution.

Comment: Okay. If you find the solution, please post it here. Thanks

Comment: I have try the solution of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921426/error-writing-to-server. It seems that it not work. I add tow more field in <tomcat_home>/conf/server.xml  file. maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxPostSize="67589953"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve this issue . Maybe there are limit of the batch method of google. I split the cells to 10000 cells one batch. And call many time batch method. And then can resolve this issue.